# How to identify username and password for phpmyadmin at the time of login for MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

While starting the phpmyadmin server for MySQL database it asks for a username and passowrd which I have not set earlier but it does not allow me to login. The error pops up everytime (uploaded the error below). How should i get out pf this situation.  [Error that pops up  while Login for MySQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnLNC.png)

I tried entering root as username and blank password.
Tried entering my emailid password.
Tried root@localhost as username and root as password

Comment: This isn’t a programming problem. There is a [duplicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232318/default-phpmyadmin-login-credentials) on a more suitable site.